# ¿como alinear los div arriba?

Tags: html, css

Mi problema es que no he logrado alinear los div de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solo se muestra así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los estilos y HTML son estos:

```css
    .marco{
     border: 1px solid #333;
    }
    .visual{
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px;
    }
    .rCalif{
     width: 24.7%;
    }
    .alineados{
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <section class="cuerpo">
      <div>
       <div class="title">
        <div class="logo img alineados"><img src="img/logo.png"></div><div class="titulo alineados"><label>Identificación del evaluado</label></div>
       </div>
       <div class="datos-eval">
       <!--Este div deveria alinearce-->
        <div class="img alineados marco top">
         <img src="img/logo.png">
        </div>
    
        <div class="datos-per alineados">
        <div class="alineados">
         <label class="marco visual">Nombre Nombre Apellido Apellido</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Antiguedad:</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Edad:</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Cargo:</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Centro de costo:</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Domicilio:</label><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Nivel de estudio:</label><br>
        </div> 
        <div class="alineados">
         <label class="visual"></label><br>
         <label id="Antiguedad" class="marco visual">2</label><br>
         <label id="edad" class="marco visual">21</label><br>
         <label id="Cargo" class="marco visual">Cargo</label><br>
         <label id="CentroCosto" class="marco visual">Centro de costo</label><br>
         <label id="Domicilio" class="marco visual">Domicilio</label><br>
         <label id="NivelEstudio" class="marco visual">Nivel de estudio</label><br>
        </div>
    
        <!--Este div deveria alinearce-->    
        <div class="alineados">
         <label class="marco visual">Fecha de evaluacion</label><br>
         <input class="marco form-control" type="text" name="fechaEvaluacion"><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Periodo de evaluacion</label><br>
         <input class="marco form-control" type="text" name="periodoEvaluacion"><br>
         <label class="marco visual">Evaluador(es)</label><br>
         <input class="marco form-control" type="text" name="periodoEvaluacion"><br>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        <div class="resultados">
         <div class="alineados rCalif">
          <label class="marco visual">% Asistencia</label><br>
          <label id="asis" class="marco visual">100</label>
         </div>
         <div class="alineados rCalif">
          <label class="marco visual">Promedio calificaciones</label><br>
          <label id="califica" class="marco visual">7</label>
         </div>
         <div class="alineados rCalif">
          <label class="marco visual">Valoracion criterios</label><br>
          <label id="criterios" class="marco visual">bueno</label>
         </div>
         <div class="alineados rCalif">
          <label class="marco visual">Valoración c. aprendizaje</label><br>
          <label id="cAprendizaje" class="marco visual">bueno</label>
         </div>
        </div>
    
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: `.alineados` si siempre van a estar de 4 en 4, puedes hacer que sean `display: block; float: left; width: 25% (o tamaños que desees poner);` o usar flex. Flex es una propiedad que poco a poco va ganando adeptos para este tipo de situaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que con:

```
 .alineados:{
            vertical-align: top;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```